# Problem with sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt

I have tried `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get clean`. Still I keep getting this error

I am running Ubuntu 12

```
siddharth@IWORKHERE:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following extra packages will be installed:   
      openjdk-7-jdk 
Suggested packages:  
visualvm 
The following packages will be upgraded:   
      openjdk-7-jdk 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded. 
Need to get 0 B/16.5 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 88.1 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y 
(Reading database ... 394130 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to replace openjdk-7-jdk 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 (using .../openjdk-7-jdk_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2_i386.deb) ... 
Unpacking replacement openjdk-7-jdk ... dpkg: error processing 
/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2_i386.deb (--unpack):  
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/src.zip', which is also in package openjdk-7-source 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 
Errors were encountered while processing:  /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2_i386.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -r openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

then finally, you are set to install that package as if it's a fresh without any trailing history of the installation.

Comment: This worked for me when the tomcat7 installation with `apt-get` failed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to force over write of that file.

please run this command `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jdk_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2_i386.deb`

then run `sudo apt-get -f install`

ref: [[SOLVED] Error ‘dpkg: error processing  (--unpack) trying to overwrite…](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/30/solved-error-dpkg-error-processing-filename-unpack-trying-to-overwrite/)

Comment: This may cause trouble e.g. when there's an update for that package. If the two files don't have the same content the program may not work as expected.